# How to sum properties grouping by onother property in an array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, grouping

I have an array, like so:

```bsh
$array = @()
$Props = [ordered]@{Table="Table1"; Col1=1; Col2=2}
$array += New-Object psobject -Property $Props
$Props = [ordered]@{Table="Table2"; Col1=4; Col2=5}
$array += New-Object psobject -Property $Props
$Props = [ordered]@{Table="Table1"; Col1=3; Col2=7}
$array += New-Object psobject -Property $Props
$Props = [ordered]@{Table="Table2"; Col1=2; Col2=6}
$array += New-Object psobject -Property $Props
```

I want to get the sum of `Col1` and `Col2`, by table:

```
Table    Col1    Col2
-----    -----   -----
Table1       4       9
Table2       6      11
```

In SQL, this would be:

```sql
SELECT Table, Col1 = SUM(Col1), Col2 = SUM(Col2)
FROM <$array>
GROUP BY Table
```

But I can't figure out how to do this in PoSh. Surely this should be relatively straightforward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the SQL statement on its head, and you basically know what to do in PowerShell - group by table name then select the sums over each of them!

```
# Group the objects by table name
$Tables = $array |Group Table

# Select the table name + sum of each group
$Tables |Select-Object Name,@{Name='Sum1';Expression={($_.Group |Measure-Object Col1 -Sum).Sum}},@{Name='Sum2';Expression={($_.Group |Measure-Object Col2 -Sum).Sum}}
```

The last two arguments to `Select-Object` are calculated expressions:

```
@{
  # Select a new property named "Sum1"
  Name = 'Sum1'
  Expression = {
    # Calculate the value from the sum of the Col1 properties in this table
    ($_.Group |Measure-Object Col1 -Sum).Sum
  }
}
```

Comment: But this gives me: `Table  Sum1 Sum2
-----  ---- ----
Table1    1    2
Table1    3    7
Table2    4    5
Table2    2    6
` which is not what I asked for.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Mathias!